# Java sorting with quicksort algorithm

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm trying to code a quicksort program in java.here is my partition function

```
int partition(int[] array, int start, int end) 
{
    int last = end - 1;
    int first = start;
    int pivot = array[start];
    while (first < last)
    {
        while (first < last && pivot <= array[last])
            last = last - 1;
        array[first] = array[last];
        while (first < last && pivot > array[first])
            first = first + 1;
        array[last] = array[first];
    }
    array[first] = pivot;
    return first;
}
```

and that is my quicksort function

```
void quickSort(int array[], int start, int end) {
      int index = partition(array, start, end);
      if (start < index - 1)
            quickSort(array, start, end - 1);
      if (index < end)
            quickSort(array, index, end);}
```

But when I test the code in Junit it gives me error. I need to change quickSort or partition function. What can I do with that.

Comment: what error it gives to you?

Comment: why are you not using Arrays.sort(int[] a)?

Comment: stack overflow error on line "quickSort(array, index, end);"

Comment: Interesting how you lost interest in updating your question with other vital information like how you call the method..(the contents of the array are relevant to your error and debugging it), and you lost interest, because now the deadline past you don't care anymore. I downvoted you 'cos you didn't even think to include a print statement, or show the other information. But since you lost interest in updating your question once the deadline passed, i'll tell you that if I could downvote you again, I would.

Comment: anybody showing a different algorithm for the purpose of answering the exercise given, is perhaps showing a clear misunderstanding of the objective of the exercise this person has been given. Obviously anybody can pull a quicksort algorithm off the internet, his lecturer knows that. The point is to find out why the particularly designed quicksort he was given fails, and to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
 if (start < index - 1)
                quickSort(array, start, end - 1);
```

Why do you call quickSort for lower partition from start, to end-1? Shouldnt it be:

```
  if (start < index - 1)
                    quickSort(array, start, index - 1);
```

And the upper part is from index+1 to end.

Moreover, it is better to check the limits like this before the partitioning and remove your if statements:

```
 if (end <= start) { return; }
```

Comment: I changed these lines but still gives error on line `             quickSort(array, index, end);
` stack overflow error it says

Comment: Did you check the if statement before the partitioning? remove those if statements before recursive calls.

Comment: You should use quickSort(array, index+1, end) in 2nd statement. Have you changed the lower part? What kind of error does it give?

Comment: @user2955896 seriously man, can't you do print to console (sometihing like system.out.println) the index, the start, and the end, and then you will be able to see what is going on. It's call debugging. It's just basic intelligence to know that if you have a problem you TRY TO FIND IT. Ever heard of debugging. i'm downvoting your question. It's utterly absurd that you have not tried to debug or asked how.. Do you even know the meaning of the word I wonder.

Comment: my mind has blown.can you explain it more clearly or write the code directly :( I'm beginner for java

Comment: @user2955896 it's actually difficult to just write the code that fixes it just by looking at it, without debugging. But it's not so difficult to debug things. I haven't done java in 10 years('so' I  don't have it installed on my system).. I must say, teaching recursion(a technique quicksort uses) when people can't debug is really tough. recursion is not an easy subject. And to practice debugging I wouldn't learn on a recursive algorithm.

Comment: I totally agree with you but can you help me for once? 2 hours left for deadline. If I can't fix the code I may fail the class

Comment: @ArtemMoskalev well, I learnt quicksort and bubblesort pretty quickly, it was very hard, but I learnt for loops and so on before that, and I learnt how to debug myself it's just obvious as the first programs you learn like hello world, do a println. A lot of people taking programming don't take the time to even learn how simple programs work, and if they lack the logic and inclination to even do that, then I don't see them having much hope when it comes to a complex  algorithm that is complex and clever enough somebody put his name to it!

Comment: @user2955896 most of your class will fail this unless they cheat and find somebody in class that knows the stuff. Even programmers will struggle. Algorithms is one of the hardest classes. the idea of coursework is problematic 'cos people cheat - understandable as it's beginning or middle of the year and they haven't learnt it yet. see how you do in the final exam. but it'll still be one of the hardest modules.

Comment: @user2955896, I gave you all the info. As long as you dont need to change the partition method, it should work well. Now, if you have errors, it means there is sth else, which I cant guess not seeing your logs.

Comment: I changed the just as you said but I still get same error(stack overflow) .The code that I wrote with your advice  void quickSort(int[] array, int start, int end) {
       int index = partition(array, start, end - 1);
       if (index+1 < end)
             quickSort(array, start, index - 1);
       if (index < end)
             quickSort(array, index, end);
}

Answer (score 0):

To me, it just seems much less intuitive to write the functions like those above.  Take this sample code that I just wrote (and tested) as an example, and see if you can understand it and use it to help you through your code.  NB: This is slightly different than yours in that it picks a pivot at random.

```
void quicksort(int[] nums)
{
    if (nums.length > 1)
    {
          quicksort(nums, 0, nums.length);
    }
}

//[left,right)
private void quicksort(int[] nums, int left, int right)
{   
    if (left < right - 1)
    {
        int position = left;
        int pivot = pickPivot(left, right);

        if (pivot != right - 1)
            swap(nums, pivot, right-1);

        for (int i = left; i < right - 1; i++)
        {
            if (nums[i] <= nums[right-1])
            {
                swap(nums, position, i);
                position++;
            }
        }

        swap(nums, position, right-1);
        quicksort(nums, left, position);
        quicksort(nums, position + 1, right);
    }
}

//[left,right)
private int pickPivot(int left, int right)
{
     return rand.nextInt(right-left) + left; // rand is a Random object
}

private void swap(int[] nums, int start, int end)
{
    int temp = nums[end];
    nums[end] = nums[start];
    nums[start] = temp;
}
```

As others have said, it can be difficult to debug recursive functions.  If you can't figure it out from here, I suggest using a debugger.  Eclipse's debugger is pretty easy to use and very helpful.  This may be frustrating and difficult to figure out, but the process is one that every programmer (should and) has to go through.

Once you think you have it figured out, use a testing function similar to this one to test it out (I would initially start off with a smaller `size` in case there are errors, this way it will be easier to debug):

```
void testQuickSort()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        int size = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
        int[] nums = new int[size];

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            nums[j] = rand.nextInt(10);

            if (rand.nextBoolean())
            {
                nums[j] *= -1;
            }
        }

        quicksort(nums);
        assert sorted(nums) == true;
    }
}  

private boolean sorted(int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > array[i+1])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.but i can only use two functions(partition and quicksort) and the pivot is the first element of the array.I'm trying to understand your code right now :)

Comment: @user2955896 I wasn't trying to give you exactly what you want.  I know what's wrong with your code and what your restrictions are.  Not trying to be a jerk or anything, but you should try to work this out.  Trust me, it will be to your benefit in the long run.

Comment: Steve I agree with you, you are so right but I'm looking for a Greg right now

Comment: @user2955896 As in GGG? I think that's what I'm being.  Sorry. :)  Good luck!  Hope you figure it out.

Comment: 2 hours left for deadline can you just give the exact code for once.I promise I will work hard in the long run :(

Comment: @user2955896 maybe you should include the entire thing.. first you didn't even include a paste of the exact error you got, into your question. so edit your question and put it there. Secondly, somewhere you call the function and give it an array. Somewhere it says public static void main, but you haven't shown it. Edit your question and show everything including array contents. You could even include screenshots since you may not be capable of typing the things in exactly and communicating clearly. So whether using a cmd prompt or an IDE, do a screenshot. I hope you improve in future!

Answer (score 0):

> stack overflow error on line "quickSort(array, index, end);

When array is big enough recusion call too many times the same function overflowing stack.

Instead of recursion place pairs of indexes in a stack and call the quickSort() for top pair.

```
void quickSort(int array[], int start, int end) {
  int index = partition(array, start, end);
  if (start < index - 1)
//        quickSort(array, start, end - 1);
        push(start, end - 1);
  if (index < end)
//        quickSort(array, index, end);}
        push(index, end);

while(stack is not empty) {
    //get next pair and call quickSort
}
```

Comment: I think you can get a stack overflow / buffer overflow, if the base case of the recursive procedure never gets reached. So he just kept hitting the recursive case until the stack overflowed. I doubt he had a giant array so big it broke his method.  And i'm sure his lecturer doesn't want people to change the design of his algorithm, rather to fix it given its design. Otherwise anybody could comment out bit sof his algorithm and replace it with something found online! The objective in an algorithms course is to test if you really understand well, the algorithm the lecturer has given.